# Passing as "file://" url to Facebook SDK WebDialog

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

Is it possible to send the url of a local file (e.g., `file:///Users/john/mypng.png`) as the `picture` parameter to the Facebook SDK `WebDialog`?

For example

```
params.putString("picture", "file:///Users/john/mypng.png");
```

Cheers.

Comment: I see.  In that case, can you suggest a way to post a local photo using a Facebook Dialog?

Comment: There's no way to post a local photo using Web dialogs. You can use an ACTION_SEND intent (plenty of discussion around that on stack overflow already), or via open graph actions using the native share dialog - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share-dialog/